# JavaScript binding event for array

Tags: javascript

How to add an array of events with JavaScript, no frames.
for example:
`var delBtn = cityList.getElementsByTagName('button');`
I want to give delBtn  binding event。
what should I do

Comment: you can iterate and bind event to that. what is difficult for you in that Mr.尚义龙?

Comment: Not suitable for fixed length